# My filter search list in react doesn't display the filtered list and runs into the error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

This is Owner component(Owner.js) where I am implementing a search filter which should display restaurant with the same name as in search. But when I try to use the restaurant and implement filter search It goes to error. I should get the list of restaurant from my pre-existing restaurant list in owner dashboard.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Restaurant from "../customer/Restaurant";

export default class Owner extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      search: ""
    };
  }
  updateSearch(event) {
    this.setState({
      search: event.target.value.substr(0, 25)
    });
  }
  render() {
    let filteredRestaurants = this.props.restaurants;

    return (
      <div>
        <h1> Welcome Owner </h1> <br />
        <ul>
          {" "}
          {filteredRestaurants.map(res => {
            return <restaurants res={<Restaurant />} key={res.name} />;
          })}
        </ul>{" "}
        <input
          type="text"
          Value={this.state.search}
          onChange={this.updateSearch.bind(this)}
        />{" "}
        <Restaurant />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

This is Restaurant.js which display the restaurant details in Owner.js.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { getRestaurant } from "../../actions/getRestaurants";

export class Restaurant extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
    // restaurants: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
    getRestaurantName: PropTypes.func
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.getRestaurant();
  }

  render() {
    const contentKeys = Object.keys(this.props.restaurants);
    // console.log(JSON.parse(this.props.restaurants))
    return (
      <div className="row">
        {contentKeys.map(t =>
          [this.props.restaurants[t]].map(res => (
            <div className="col-md">
              <div className="card" style={cardWidth}>
                <img className="card-img-top" src="..." alt="Card image cap" />
                <div className="card-body">
                  <h5 className="card-title">{res.Name}</h5>
                  <p className="card-text">
                    <h6>{res.Address}</h6>
                    <h6>{res.City}</h6>
                    <h6>{res.zipcode}</h6>
                    <h6>Open:{res.Hours.Open}</h6>
                    <h6>Close:{res.Hours.Close}</h6>
                  </p>
                  <a href="#" className="btn btn-primary">
                    Go somewhere
                  </a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          ))
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const cardWidth = {
  width: "18rem"
};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  restaurants: state.restaurantReducer.restaurants
});

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  { getRestaurant }
)(Restaurant);
//export default  Restaurant;
```

I am having an error in filtering restaurant from owner dashboard. As return statement does not return any value and runs into error.

```
{filteredRestaurants.map(res => {
            return <restaurants res={<Restaurant />} key={res.name} />;
          })}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're storing search query in a state, but don't use it when rendering filteredRestaurants.

You should filter them before mapping. Something like that:

```
        const filteredRestaurants = this.props.restaurants.filter(res => res.name.includes(this.state.search);

        // ...

        filteredRestaurants.map(res => <Restaurant key={res.name} />)
```

Also, you can make it much easier with [React Hooks API](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usestate), if you're using 16.8+ React.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But my return option doesn't work. My return function doesn't return anything.

Comment: @madhavkoirala do you have another error? I didn't check rest part, since the question was about search function.

Comment: Yes, my search function is not returning any value and runs into the error.

Comment: have you noticed an example of how .map should return components in my code?

Comment: this is my return for search filter and I am using restaurant from Restaurant.js. So I want to return the restaurant in same format it was before filter search. 
** {filteredRestaurants.map(res => {return <restaurants res={<Restaurant />} key={res.name} />;**
          })}`

Comment: this code won't work becauseyou don't have `<restaurants/>` component inside Restaurant.js file